# Приложение для IOS с видеозаписью на сервере

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone, swift, apple

Появилась потребность разработки приложения для *IOS* с возможностью записи видео с камеры телефона на сервер.

У меня есть веб-приложение, которое работает на *webrtc* и сервере *kurento*, все работает отлично, но на *IOS webrtc* не работает, по крайней мере в браузере (*ericsson bowser* не предлагать, в связке с *kurento* не работает; или предлагать, если известна альтернатива куренты для серверной стороны).

С использованием каких технологий можно это реализовать на *IOS*? (то же *webrtc* в нативном приложении будет работать? если да, что использовать на удаленном сервере для записи видео?)

Можно ли как-то использовать *adobe media server* для записи видео из приложения на *ios*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960782/upload-live-streaming-video-from-iphone-like-ustream-or-qik

Answer (score 1):

Если погуглить, то можно найти два варианта:

1. [OpenWebRTC](http://www.openwebrtc.io). Серьезная библиотека с хорошей документацией. Если у
   вас есть проблемы с этим, то советую копать все-таки в сторону
   сервера, возможно что-то настроено неправильно. Так-же можно
   использовать OpenWebRTC и на сервере.
2. Официальная библиотека [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/ios). На [Github](https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios) есть пример использования.